# Building aar library from multimodule project

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, aar, android-module

I've got a multi-module Android project which have one module called `app` which is the Android application, that contains `features` where each `feature` is separate module.

I would like to extract one of the feature modules as a `aar` library.

I started from creating a `demo` app inside the project that have my feature module as a dependency:

`implementation project(':player')`

I adjusted the code of the app to make it working and in my Demo app inside the project it was working as expected.

My next step was to build the `aar` file and include it in separate project. I did it by using task:

Gradle -> `player` -> Tasks -> build -> build

After importing created `aar` file in new project I'm getting a lot of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` exceptions because classes from modules that `player` module depends on are not in the generated `.jar` file.

I didn't mention, but `player` module depends on few other modules like `domain`, `base-android`, `data` and so on and it seems like all of those modules are not included in `aar` file.

At first I thought that changing from `implementation` for those modules to `api` will solve the problem, but it didn't.

My question is: is there something I'm missing while building the `aar` library? I thought that if something is working great when included in the module within one project then it should also work like that when after creating a `aar` file, but it seems like it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting ClassNotFoundException as your module's aar doesn't contains your other submodules' code or aar files. To fix this issue you can check out this gradle plugin that will include all sub modules's arr into your main module automatically. Check out fat AAR, here is the link : https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android